# Deutscher Ausdruck für „guilty pleasure“?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, phrase-request

Im Englischen gibt es den Ausdruck „guilty pleasure“ ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilty_pleasure), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guilty_pleasure)), mit dem man beispielsweise einen Film bezeichnen kann, den man sehr gerne sieht, obwohl man weiß, dass der Film schlecht ist (oder eher: von anderen als schlecht angesehen wird). Oft (aber wohl nicht immer) ist es einem auch peinlich, diesen Film zu gucken oder gut zu finden.

(Zumindest verstehe ich die Bedeutung so; ich selber habe den Begriff noch nie verwendet.)

**Gibt es dafür einen deutschen Ausdruck?**

Als Übersetzung [schlägt dict.cc vor](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/guilty+pleasure.html):

- Laster
- heimliches Vergnügen

Ich finde aber, dass diese Begriffe nicht so ganz passen (zumindest für die von mir beschriebene Bedeutung). Wenn man einen peinlichen/schlechten Film gerne hat, ist das ja noch kein Laster (womöglich wird es zu einem Laster, wenn man nicht mehr von diesem Film loskommt und ihn immer wieder guckt) und das Vergnügen am Film ist ja nicht notwendigerweise „heimlich“.

Bei [phrasen.com wird vorgeschlagen](http://www.phrasen.com/uebersetze,guilty-pleasure,82718,e.html):

- Vergnügen mit Gewissensbissen

Abgesehen davon, dass ich diesen Ausdruck noch nie gehört habe, finde ich „Gewissensbisse“ etwas zu hart in diesem Kontext.

Bisher ist mir nur „peinliches Vergnügen“ eingefallen, aber es ist ja nicht zwangsläufig *peinlich*.

Comment: Für Musik kenne ich _Popsünde_.

Comment: Beachte, dass es nicht immer für jedes Wort / jeden Ausdruck einer Sprache eine Entsprechung in einer anderen geben kann. Sprachen sind kulturell beeinflusst und somit teilweise gar nicht übersetzbar, wenn der Sinn nicht übermittel werden kann.

Comment: Ich finde "Laster" trifft es noch am besten. Alles andere sind eher Umschreibungen.

Comment: "laster" finde ich auch recht passend

Comment: Muss es ein Substantiv (mit Begleiter) sein? _leider geil, sich gönnen/erlauben/herausnehmen_

Comment: "Schwäche" could also be used as a translation - "Ich habe eine schwäche für ..."

Answer (score 6):

Ich hab noch ***sündiges Vergnügen*** gefunden. Hab ich persönlich so noch nicht gehört in einer Unterhaltung.

Zusätzlich ist mir noch ***sündhaftes Vergnügen*** eingefallen. Ähnlich wie bei *sündhaft teuer* weiß derjenige, dass das Produkt zu kaufen (oder in deinem Beispiel, den Film zu gucken) vielleicht keine rationale Rechtfertigung hat und eventuell sogar von anderen als "*mit einer Sünde behaftet*" angesehen wird, er (oder sie) tut es aber trotzdem, weil es ein Vergnügen ist und man sich dabei/danach besser fühlt.

In dem Zusammenhang gibt es auch den Ausspruch, dass etwas *eine Sünde Wert* sei (zum Beispiel Schokolade essen, obwohl man es eigentlich nicht sollte).

Comment: _sündiges Verlangen_

Comment: Begriffe, die vom Wort *Sünde* abstammen, haben für mich eine zu starke religiöse Konnotation um sie in so einem Zusammenhang zu verwenden. Im Englischen ist (aus gutem Grund) ja auch nicht von *sinful pleasure* die Rede, sondern von *guilty pleasure*.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde *guilty pleasure* vielleicht mit *reuiges Vergnügen* (oder *Vergnügen mit Reue*) oder, je nach Kontext, mit *Genuss mit schlechtem Gewissen* übersetzen.

Comment: *Reuiges Vergnügen* gefällt mir am besten von allen bisherigen Vorschlägen, weil es nicht so hart wie *sündhaft* oder *sündig* ist und in meinen Ohren auch gut klingt (vielleicht auch weil ich das Wort *reuig* eher selten höre oder verwende).

Answer (score 3):

Meiner Meinung nach stellt **heimliches Vergnügen** die Bedeutung am besten dar. Wie du selber erwähnt hast, ein *guilty pleasure* muss ja nicht heimlich sein, im Sinne davon, dass es wirklich dem Ruf von jdm. oder sonst etwas schaden würde. Trotzdem sollte es heimlich verbleiben, weil es demjenigen sonst peinlich wäre.

Es ist meines Erachtens ein scherzhafter Ausdruck. Von daher kann man auch vielleicht mal das Wort *schadenfroh* erwähnen. **Ein schadenfrohes Vergnügen**.

Es schadet ja bloß der Würde ein wenig, sobald das *Geheimnis* rauskommt, aber im Nachhinein kann es sogar etwas Liebenswertes sein. Ähnlich wie die **peccadillos** (DE: das Kavaliersdelikt), die man bspw. von seiner Frau kennt – nur er kennt sie.

Laster finde ich persönlich auch nicht so passend. Damit verknüpfe ich zusätzlich eine negative Nebenbedeutung – ein Gefühl, dass ich mit einem *guilty pleasure* gar nicht verbinde.

Nur, um es gesagt zu haben: viele Freunde von mir sagen einfach "guilty pleasure", während sie ansonsten auf Deutsch sprechen.

Comment: Mit Schadenfreude hat guilty pleasure nichts zu tun, und mit heimlich auch meistens nicht.

Comment: Die Frage muss dann wohl ein subjektives Thema darstellen. Heimlich ist es - da gibt's meiner Meinung nach nichts zu besprechen. I would say that I don't feel guilty because of the fact... Does that mean it is no longer a guilty pleasure?

Answer (score 2):

Mir fällt kein Ausdruck im Sinne von ein oder zwei Wörtern ein. Ich würde im genannten Zusammenhang eher den folgenden Satz benutzen:

> Das ist so schlecht (oder: kitschig / übertrieben...), dass es schon
>   wieder gut ist.

Comment: Das geht an der Frage vorbei. Es ging nicht darum, wie man den schlechten Film in diesem Beispiel nennt, sondern den Akt, sich diesen anzugucken; im vollem Bewusstsein, wie schlecht er ist.

Answer (score 1):

An sich ist das ein *peinliches Vergnügen*, wenn man meint, sich schämen zu müssen, dass man beim Kucken dieses Films seinen Spaß hat.

Das sollte die beste wörtliche Übersetzung sein. Eine stehende Wendung so wie im Englischen stellt diese Übersetzung allerdings nicht dar.

Answer (score 0):

Gerade Phrasen und Redewendungen kann man sehr oft nicht eins zu eins von einer Sprache in eine andere übersetzen. Da muss man eben akzeptieren, dass man das in der Zielsprache irgendwie umschreiben muss, und das trifft eben auch auf »guilty pleasure« zu. Auch »it's raining cats and dogs« oder »a different kettle of fish« kann man so nicht ins Deutsche übersetzen, sondern muss dafür Umschreibungen finden.

Auch umgekehrt gibt es massenhaft deutsche Idiome, die man auch nicht so einfach z.B. ins Englische übersetzen kann:

- das ist unter aller Sau
- er hat schon einiges auf dem Kerbholz
- ist dir eine Laus über die Leber gelaufen?
- *usw.*

Answer (score -1):

Vielleicht „schuldbewusstes Vergnügen“? Ich bin mir meiner „Schuld“ über die Peinlichkeit, z.B. des Filmes bewusst, habe aber dennoch mein Vergnügen daran.

Comment: Die Anführungszeichen um "Schuld" sollen was ausdrücken? Unsicherheit? Dass der Hörer nicht _Schuld_ verstehen soll, sondern was anderes? Wieso sagst Du dann nichts anderes? Und "Schuld über"?