# Is there a German word for a food that a person likes but is bad for their body?

Tags: single-word-request

Friends and I have been discussing diets and their effects on our bodies. One friend is following quite a restrictive diet due to digestion issues (intolerance, not allergy). However, she still likes the taste of many foods that disagree with her (e.g. they cause bloating, stomach ache).

One of our friends quipped:

> We need a word for those foods where the person loves the food but the food sadly does not love them back.

Is there such a word in German?

Comment: For (expensive) calory-bombs you like, there's the nice expression "Hüftgold" - That literally means "gold-plates your hips". Doesn't quite fit here, though.

Comment: You can say that you have a "Hassliebe Beziehung" with that food... But I don't think it quite matches what you are saying...

Comment: Are you aware of an English word?

Comment: @Thomas: Im Englischen könnte man *guilty pleasure* hierfür zweckentfremden, auch wenn es ursprünglich für etwas anderes genutzt wurde. Wir haben sogar [eine Frage hierzu](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/26098/2594).

Comment: Not a word for the food itself, but when eating it, it would be quite fitting to say: “Das werde ich bereuen.”

Comment: @Thomas I'm not. "Junk food" is bad for people in general but I can't think of any English word for food that is bad for a specific person because of their specific medical issues.

Comment: Wow, 11 'answers' by now, all of which are not actually answering the question.

Comment: Attribute: _leider geil_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can not think of a word for that kind of food. However, a commonly used term when you eat or drink something you know is not good for you is *sündigen* (*to sin* or *to indulge*).

> Gestern habe ich wieder gesündigt und eine ganze Tafel Schokolade gegessen...

Comment: The question is for a name of the relevant food and not for the act of consuming it.

Comment: I know. That why I wrote that I know of no word for that kind of food. And I see nothing wrong in providing a commonly used colloquial expression.

Comment: +1 for a very nice portmanteau. New question, does German have aword for "portmanteau" which has that meaning ?  :-)  http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34696/portmanteau-not-handkoffer

Comment: Where's the portmanteau? *Sündigen* isn't.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Maybe this answer can be improved slightly: Along your line of thought, the word "Sünde" (sin) can be used for that kind of food. When the word is used in that sense however, it is important to make clear through context that it refers to a kind of food. Otherwise, the default assumption of the reader would be to read it as "sin".

Comment: @Madoc Actually it does not refer to the food/drink/etc. itself. The sin is to consume something that is not good for you.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar No, not necessarily. Or not in that strict sense. You can actually call the food in question "Sünde" and be perfectly understood by germans. Even though, very strictly speaking of course, you are right. The act of consuming it would be called "Sünde", not the food itself. But since this is colloquial anyways, people tend to be not completely strict about it.

Comment: As there does not seem to be a word for the food, I'm happy to credit the answer for the act of indulging in the food. Thanks. :)

Comment: _Kann denn [Chili] Sünde sein?_ _Wie kann etwas, das so gut schmeckt, mir so sehr auf den Magen schlagen?_

Answer (score 5):

A food that attracts you but you know is not good for you is a temptation. The German word for this is

> Versuchung

Although a temptation needs not be a sort of food, and its strict definition really means the stimulus created by a particular situation, the term is often used in that context. Given the situation,

> Ich sollte dieser Tafel Schokolade widerstehen

and

> Ich sollte dieser Versuchung widerstehen

are really synonymous.

Comment: _die größte/süßeste/… Versuchung seit es Sodbrennen gibt_

Comment: Auch wenn es dick macht (wenn man andere Kalorienzufuhr nicht entsprechend drosselt) ist Schokolade keine schädliche Substanz - der Part fehlt völlig.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn die Schokolade nicht schadet, ist deren Genuss ja wohl auch keine Versuchung. Der Begriff Versuchung macht nur Sinn, wenn ihr nachzugeben einen negativen Effekt hätte. Das wäre dann ja auch eine Sünde. (Konsistent mit der Antwort von Thorsten Dittmar. Nur bezeichnet Sünde eher die Handlung des Nachgebens, während die Versuchung die Situation davor meint, also eher im Sinne der ursprüglichen Frage.)

Comment: @Peter: Laut christlichen Werten und Wurzeln ist die Völlerei eine Todsünde. Statt an das Leiden Jesu zu denken und ihm nachzufolgen heftet sich das Schlemmermäulchen ans verderbte Diesseits. Das ist die Tradition der Idee vom sündigen Genuss. Diese wurde inzwischen der Ideologie der schlanken Linie geopfert, die für den gesunden Körper steht. Der negative Effekt ist keineswegs unstrittig - jede Menge Schokolade läßt sich in ein Kalorienäquivalent trocken Brot oder Salzkartoffeln umrechnen, die selten als Versuchung bezeichnet werden. Die Hingabe a.d. Lust ist die Sünde, nicht die Kalorien.

Comment: @userunknown das sehe ich alles genau so. Das ändert trotzdem nichts an der Tatsache, dass, gegeben eine konkrete Situation, in der die Lust an den Kalorien als Versuchung bezeichnet werden kann, in der Umgangssprache das Wort Versuchung als Platzhalter für das Objekt der Begierde, also die Kalorien, werwendet wird. Die gestellte Frage habe ich  hier (mangels einen besseren Begriffs) in diesem Sinne beantwortet.

Comment: Der praktische Unterschied zw. Kalorien oder allergische Reaktionen auslösenden Stoffen ist, dass man im ersten Fall jemanden vielleicht überreden will, dieses eine Mal doch zu sündigen - bei einer Allergie aber sicher nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe ja auch (vielleicht unter Anderem genau deshalb) nicht Sünde, sondern Versuchung als Begriff vorgeschlagen. Laut Wikipedia ist die Definition von letzterem: "Der Anreiz oder die Verleitung zu einer Handlung, die reizvoll erscheint, jedoch unzweckmäßig ist, einer sozialen Norm widerspricht bzw. verboten ist." Eine Allergie ist unzweckmäßig, und z.B. der Besuch eines Katzenbesitzers, wenn man eine Katzenallergie hat, kann reizvoll erscheinen, wenn es sich um eine geliebte Person handelt. Insofern handelt es sich um eine Versuchung, ganz ohne Kalorien.

Comment: Eine Allergie ist nicht unzweckmäßig. Nicht, weil sie im Gegenteil zweckmäßig wäre, sondern weil an einer Allergie zu leiden nicht der Willkür des Betroffenen unterliegt und damit keinem Zweck Die Kategorie Zweck ist hier fehl am Platze. Desungeachtet genügt es nicht, dass auch Allergien von Deinem Ausdruck umfasst wären, sondern er ist zu weit und trennt eben weder von Verboten, noch von sozialen Normverletzungen. Die Frage zielt eindeutig auf einen Begriff, der einen körperlichen Schaden als drohende Konsequenz beschreibt.

Comment: Eine Allergie ist nicht unzweckmäßig, aber sich dieser bewusst auszusetzen schon. Und wenn der Begriff nicht scharf genug trennt, heisst noch nicht, dass ihn anzuwenden, falsch wäre. Insbesondere kann der Begriff in Ermangelung eines spezifischeren Begriffs der auf die Situation am besten passende sein. Welcher der aufgeführten Begriffe behagt Ihnen denn besser?

Answer (score 3):

The negative effects of the food can best be covered by

> schlecht bekömmlich, unbekömmlich, nicht bekömmlich

(This means sort of *causing trouble*, restricting this to food/wellness topic.)

I'm not aware of any word expressing that in combination with addictiveness.

Comment: Vielleicht passt noch *giftig* in diese Aufzählung. Allerdings inkludiert keiner der Begriffe, dass die Speise demjenigen schmeckt.

Comment: -1 because this does not cover the question.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Given, that noboday else suggested a striking translation and considering that no language is guaranteed to supply a given counterpiece (the question did not provide a word for English either) I find this out of the responsibility of my answer.

Comment: Well, I think, when you do not have an answer to the question, you should refuse to answer at all. Or tell the questioner that there is no such counterpiece they are looking for (and offer some sort of proof). Everything else will lead to a bunch of unsatisfactory answers.

Comment: _willkommen aber unbekömmlich_

Answer (score 2):

The lack of definite answers shows that there is no established (compound) word or phrase for an enjoyable meal with predetermined bad aftermath. Here are some ideas anyhow.

- *Lustmahl, Lustspeise, Lustfraß, Lustessen* – sexual connotation of *Lust* may be too strong
- *Bauchspeise/Herzspeise/Halsspeise, Wohlfühlspeise/Gefühlsspeise* vs. *Kopfspeise/Hirnspeise, Vernunftspeise* – cf. *Bauchgefühl, Bauchentscheidung, Hals über Kopf, Herz statt Hirn, Kopf sagt Nein doch Bauch/Herz sagt Ja, Leibspeise …*
- *kleine/lässliche (kulinarische) Sünde*
- *unwiderstehliche/köstliche Versuchung*
- *köstlicher/genussvoller/kalkulierter/bewusster Fehler*
- *Unwiderstehlichkeit*
- *Lieblingsfehler*
- *gefährliche Köstlichkeit*
- *Geschmacksfalle*
- *nachbeschwerter/folgenschwerer Genuss* – cf. *unbeschwerter Genuss*
- *… mit Konsequenzen*, *… wider besseren Wissens*, *… ist die Folgen wert*, *… jederzeit wieder*

Comment: 1, 2 drücken keinerlei Gefahr aus, 3, 4, 5, 6 stehen für Kalorienbomben, 7 siehe 1, *nachbeschwert*?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no word for that in German.

Comment: How can you be sure?

Comment: Weil ich in Deutschland geboren bin und seid über 30 Jahren in Deutschland lebe und noch nie so ein Wort gehört habe. Manchmal gibt es für bestimmte Dinge einfach kein Wort. Zum Beispiel gibt es im Deutschen auch kein Wort für nicht mehr durstig sein. Auch wenn schonmal versucht wurde dafür ein Wort zu finden. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitt

Comment: You can never be sure and certainly not that absolute. Being born somewhere probably doesn’t make you a know-it-all. There’s regional variance, technical terms, sociolects and simply words you didn’t know. Also, in this case, we already got some suggestions, and it didn’t need to be a *single* word. Furthermore, *sitt* is a lame example, since some people tried to coin it in some competition. Language doesn’t work that way. It works however for *undurstig*, *satt* und *nicht durstig*.

Comment: @DavidRicherby et. al. Ich schlage vor die Antwort upzuvoten bis jemand mit einem gebräuchlichen Begriff vorbeikommt, der uns überzeugt, dass wir falsch lliegen, und es doch einen Begriff gibt.

Comment: @userunknown: Welchen Sinn hat das Upvoten einer „Antwort“ die *jedwede* Möglichkeit ausschließt? Auch wurde *nicht* gefragt nach einem *gebräuchlichen* Begriff. Es gibt bereits viele Vorschläge – darunter gebräuchliche, alleine von Crissov/guidot sowie der akzeptierten Antwort. Wieso also sollte man ein plumpes Generaldementi „so lange upvoten“??

Comment: @dakab: Weil die Antworten falsch sind. Aus Verlegenheit upvoten, weil es zu einer anderen, ähnlichen Frage, eine gute Antwort wäre, finde ich falsch. Insbesondere weil es so viele falsche Antworten gibt und viele wohl meinen Downvotes wären als persönliche Verletzungen zu vermeiden, ist das eine weitere Möglichkeit den Dissenz zu sammeln.

Comment: Persönlich finde ich die akzeptierte Antwort nicht schlecht, aber auch nicht vollkommen passend. _Sündigen_ ist sicher ziemlich nah dran und kann im Kontext auch verwendet werden. Trotzdem ist es natürlich nicht genau das gesuchte Wort. Sündigen im Konext von Essen verbinde ich nur mit Kalorien also z.B. Schokolade. Ich verbinde es aber nicht mit Allergien oder Intoleranzen. Wenn ich eine Allergie habe auf ein Lebensmittel und esse es trotzdem, ist das für mich nicht mehr Sündigen. Das ist in dem Kontext für mich zu schwach.

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can currently come up with is "Droge" - Note this directly translates to *drug* in English, but the German term does only refer to the "illegal" sort of stuff.

> Kartoffelchips? Ich vertrag' sie nicht, aber das ist halt meine Droge. Ich kann's einfach nicht lassen.

Comment: Why the downvotes? +1 because I know a lot of people who are addicted to chocolate (and call it their drug).

Comment: Alkohol ist eine legale Droge, Zigaretten und andere Nikotinformen ebenso, Coffein, ... Der Begriff *illegale Drogen* macht schon klar, dass es wohl auch legale gibt.

Comment: @userunknown In der Umgangssprache wird niemand von einem *Raucher* oder *Säufer* oder gar Kaffeetrinker als *Drogensüchtigen* reden. Alleine schon der Begriff *Alltagsdroge* zeigt, dass "Droge" alleine nicht dafür steht.

Comment: Falsch. Genau das zeigt der Begriff. Er engt ja das allgemeine "Droge" auf eine Teilmenge ein, muss also in der allgemeinen Form diese umfassen. Vielleicht machst Du auch mal einen Abstecher zur Drogenbeauftragten der Bundesregierung, auch die befasst sich mit Alkohol und Niikotin. Und da Alkoholismus ein Massenphänomen ist kennen viele Alkoholiker aus Entgiftung und Therapie die Bedeutung des Wortes. Disclosure: Ich habe beruflich mit Drogentherapie zu tun.

Comment: @userunknown Du hast das dritte Wort in meinem Kommentar gelesen?

Comment: Ja, habe ich, und in der Frage nicht gefunden. "Ụm·gangs·spra·che/Substantiv [die]/die Sprache, mit der man sich im Alltag normalerweise verständigt." Da steht nicht, dass es die Sprache ist, in der Du, tofro, sich normalerweise verständigt. Du musst damit leben, dass sich unterschiedliche Menschen unterschiedlich verständigen. WP: "Die Umgangssprache im ersten Sinn wird geprägt durch regionale und soziale Gegebenheiten wie dem Bildungs­stand und dem sozialen Milieu der Sprechenden oder der Situation."

Answer (score -3):

The first word which comes in my mind is "Dickmacher" (literally fat/thickmaker)

eg. http://www.rp-online.de/leben/gesundheit/ernaehrung/das-sind-dickmacher-bid-1.2240310

However the Word "Junkfood" is used as well in German.
I recently heard that the orthorexic husband of a collegue refered to her lunch as "Du isst wieder Müll!" Perhaps the "Junk" from Junkfood will be germanized again.

Comment: Both terms don't necessarily refer to food a person actually *likes*. You can well say "Ich mag keine Chips - das sind Dickmacher".

Comment: I disagree. For me, neither "Dickmacher" nor "Junkfood" describe food which is responsible for intolerance issues.

Comment: Junkfood is not necessarily a "Dickmacher".

Answer (score -3):

I recommend the phrase *mein Gift*.

> Schokolade ist mein Gift.

*Chocolate is my poison.*

> Wenn ich zwischen Broccoli und Tofu entscheiden müsste, wären Zitronen das Gift meiner Wahl.

*If I had to choose between broccoli and tofu, lemons would be the poison of my choice.*

Comment: Das ist mir eigentlich zu "amerikanisch", wo einen der Barmann nach "what's your poison" fragt. Ich kenne diese Verwendung aus dem Deutschen nicht.

Comment: *Jedes Ding ist ein Gift, es kommt nur auf die Dosis an.* ist aber geläufig. Von Rauchern habe ich schon gehört *Ich lass mir doch mein täglich Gift nicht von Gesundheitsaposteln schlechtreden.* So abwegig ist es ja auch nicht, Genussmittel als Gift zu bezeichnen.

Comment: _solange es mich nicht umbringt_

Answer (score -3):

Just for fun, I invented (I believe) this portmanteau:

> Suchtualien

From **Sucht**mittel and Vikt**ualien**

Answer (score -3):

> Kalorienbombe :: calorie bomb

This stands for food which makes you fat, usually cake, chocolate, chips and all this stuff. In general this is food which is not recommended in any way.

But I would like to make a clear difference to food which hurts you or makes aches. This is seldom and only applied to people who have major intolerances and allergies. There is no special term for it. I am not an expert but I think your brain or body has some mechanism which are self-learning to prevent you from eating this (allergies are special here). So I am in doubt that you like food very long which really hurts you.

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know there is no word for that type of food but there is a word for the craving of these foods **Heißhunger**. Heißhunger is defined in the Duden dictionary as:

> A sudden, fierce hunger for a specific type of food: 
>   http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heiszhunger (Translation mine)

In common speech this word is commonly used to refer to unhealthy foods, especially sweets. It is not exactly what you are looking for but I feel its the closest to the sentiment you are looking for.

Comment: The question is for a name of the relevant food and not for a name of the feeling you have when craving for it.