# Portmanteau - not Handkoffer

Tags: single-word-request

Inspired by @ThorstenDittmar's very amusing answer to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34682/is-there-a-german-word-for-a-food-that-a-person-likes-but-is-bad-for-their-body):

Google for the English word "portmanteau", and you will find that it has two meanings

> 1. a large travelling bag, typically made of stiff leather and opening into two equal parts.
> 2. a word blending the sounds and combining the meanings of two others, for example motel or brunch.
>
>    "podcast is a portmanteau, a made-up word coined from a combination of
>      the words iPod and broadcast"

When I Google translate "portmanteau", it suggests only Handkoffer.

Does German have a word, or phrase, for the second meaning of "portmanteau"?

Comment: I don't get how @ThorstenDittmar inspired this question.

Comment: By using the word "gesündigt", which is a portmanteau

Comment: how is "gesündigt" a portmanteau? "Sündigen" is just an normal verb.

Comment: Unless I make a mistake, he portmanteaus gesund and sündig. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, now I understand your idea, but unfortunately, that is a mistake. "Gesündigt" is the normal Perfekt tense of "sündigen". A common phrase is: "Vater, vergibt mir. Ich habe gesündigt." (Father forgive me, I have sinned).

Comment: So, how can we make it a funny portmanteau? Is it possible? Can I make it "ich habe gesündig gegessen?"

Comment: "Gesündigt" is just not funny and I can't think of any funny portmanteau. Beta gave an portmanteau as an answer here (http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34682/is-there-a-german-word-for-a-food-that-a-person-likes-but-is-bad-for-their-body), but the minus votes show that people don't think it is a good new word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteauwort) knows this word and also states that it is sometimes called "Schachtelwort" or "Kofferwort".

Comment: *Kofferwort* is the term most known.

Comment: In contrast to @Janka, I didn't know *Kofferwort* at all, but I'm very familiar with *Schachtelwort* (and also *Portmanteau* in this meaning). So without actual data I'm not sure which one is most known.